# D3 Pie Chart Render Only Once In Side *NgFor Angular

Tags: angular, d3.js, charts

I'm creating a dashboard with angular 8.for render charts I'm using `d3.js`.I want to render 3 `pie charts` in side 3 sibling `div`s. but only the first div renders the pie chart other divs are empty.i could be the cause for this.this is working example for in a [pei chart stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-and-d3-ek6r8w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpie%2Fpie.component.ts)

Comment: could you provide a stackblitz of your problem too?

Comment: My bad I attached wrong example above I corrected that.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-and-d3-ek6r8w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpie%2Fpie.component.ts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `d3.select` always selects the first svg. I would use a `@ViewChild` to get the right element and change the `OnInit` code to `AfterViewInit`

Here is the fixed [version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-and-d3-pies).